# open a completion popup from normal mode

Tags: vim, omnicomplete

Gived this script (packages suggestion was simplified, original takes care of <cword>)

```
function! CompleteImport()
  let packages = ['java.util.Vector','java.lang.String']
  call complete(col('.'),packages)
  return ''
endfunction

inoremap <F8> import <C-R>=CompleteImport()<CR>
```

while on insert mode you can add an import and choose between suggested packages pressing <kbd>F8</kbd>

But I want to be enable to reach that popup selection from normal mode

```
function! InsertImport() 
   exe "normal iimport \<C-R>=CompleteImport()\<CR>"
   "this commented line would work too
   "exe "normal i\<F8>" 
endfunction 

map <Leader>ji :call InsertImport()<CR>
```

so from normal mode `,ji` (stands for java import) add an import to word under cursor if it is found

(Move to right position is not a problem so I ommit here)

By now `,ji` adds first suggestion from popup and exists insert mode

I have tried `:startinsert` but no luck.

see on http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#:execute there is a suggested code:

```
:execute "normal ixxx\<Esc>"
```

but that final <kbd>Esc</kbd> doesn't matter at all (for my vim install at least) This do exactly the same for me:

```
:execute "normal ixxx"
```

I would think this is not possible if I haven't found that on docs. So, it's possible to stay on a popup calling from a function?

Other interested docs:

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:normal
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#:startinsert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:startinsert` usually is the right approach, but it indeed gives control back to the user, so you cannot automatically trigger the completion.

Through the `feedkeys()` function, you can send arbitrary keys "as if typed". This allows you to start insert mode *and* trigger the completion:

```
function! InsertImport()
    call feedkeys("iimport \<C-R>=CompleteImport()\<CR>", 't')
endfunction
nnoremap <Leader>ji :call InsertImport()<CR>
```

PS: [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html) for the normal mode mapping, too; it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

Comment: Thanks! Here is a full functional implementation for autoimport feature https://github.com/albfan/vim-jide.git